# bindFromRequest and asFormUrlEncoded return different values

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a form where a field name is the same as one of the method/url parameters on the submit, say `someInt`. I.e. my form has `@(dummyForm:Form[Dummy], someInt:Int)` and `dummyForm` has a field `"someInt" -> number` and the controller is defined as `def submit(someInt:Int) =...`. [Sample code here.](https://gist.github.com/wwkudu/28bb110b92ff6155ad9e)

Let's say I submit the form with dummy.someInt value 222 and url parameter 555, I find the following:

- `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded` shows one someInt, namely the value entered in the input field: `(someInt,ArrayBuffer(222))`
- `bindFromRequest`, however somehow binds the form value to the url parameter value, `555` in this case

Is this expected behaviour? I would have thought `bindFromRequest` would be able to differentiate between the two? Is there a preferred way to prevent this type of conflict (besides having different names)?

(There is a workaround in this case. Instead of using the parameterless version of `bindFromRequest`, it seems to work as desired if you explicitly specify the `asFormUrlEncoded` set of values, i.e. `bindFromRequest(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.getOrElse(Map()))`. I am using Scala - have not tried to replicate in Java.)

Comment: tried this in play java and getting the same output as described by your problem.I also dont know if this is the expected behaviour.Trying to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [bindFromRequest](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.7/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L86) function, `request.queryString` is explicitly append to the list of values.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I looked at that code, but didn't look all the way to the end. I wonder what the reason for that is? Anyhow, it seems the explicit asFormUrlEncoded is the only way to go then.

Comment: There is probably a good reason, but does anyone know why queryString is appended. the order of Map keys is not guaranteed afaik so in the case of a field name and url parameter having the same name, it would be unpredictable which value bindFromRequest would return...